# Noise reduction algorithm for an AC mains voltage measurement

Tags: microcontroller, c, dsp

I am measuring and displaying the mains voltage at six inputs with a 12-bit ADC. To make the calculation simple and fast I am only using 11 bits. I am sampling the 50 Hz sine wave at 20 points using a timer and then averaging the same, and then converting to RMS by multiplying with a factor. The six inputs are interleaved (I hope its the correct term). I am getting accurate values within +/- 1 ~ 2 volts. The only problem is the values are jumping around the mean value by 1 ~ 2 volts. So for a voltage of 230 V it will jump around from 228 V to 232 V. While the accuracy is acceptable, the display looks ugly because of this jumping.

What would be the best and computationally fastest way to reduce this "noise"/"jitter"?

Comment: Are you certain that your mains voltage isn't actually jumping about? Maybe your measurements are accurate ...

Comment: Sliding average of the past n readings?  Only update the display if the measured value is more than x Volts above/below the displayed value?  Force an update frequency of y seconds?  All of the above?

Comment: If your sampling is not referenced to the zero-cross so that each sample occurs at the same angle for each successive cycle then I would expect that much jitter on your readings. Is it zero-cross referenced?

Comment: How are you taking the samples? Don't forget that mains frequency is not always exactly 50 (or 60) Hz... However, calculate a "slipping mean" on the voltage with, at least, 5 "calculated mean". Note also that if you take sample every 1 ms (timer for 50 Hz, or 20 ms), you need 21 points...

Comment: Note also that "Simpson" formula for calculating mean is also "interesting".

Comment: Mumbai, I think you need to first do the very best you can to capture measurement data. This means, as @Transistor says, synchronizing measurements to the zero-cross or else (this pops to mind) use the autocorrelation function (I think that may work fine, given some more thought, but that's another topic.) With that in hand, I think you can then work on techniques to smooth the measurements for visual purposes. But the measurement data comes first. Then smoothing. And you must make sure you apply the right techniques, too.

Comment: @Transistor I am not cross referencing it to zero, because I don't have sufficient pins for zero crossing detection.I am using a timer based trigger interrupt to begin every new sampling cycle.I am "assuming" that every new cycle computation will begin at the same point on the sine wave.

Comment: @Antonio51 The problem is the multimeter jumps around by only 1Volt. I am refreshing my display at 2Hz, same as a multimeter readiing. I will read about Simpson formula. I will check my code again for 21 measuring points :-) !

Comment: Ok. 1 volt on 220 V is not so bad. The refreshing rate is a bit too "low" (choose 2s) because of the fluctuation of voltage mains. Note also that the "mean" may be also a "fast" fluctuating "variable". It is not "jitter".

Answer (score 2):

> *I am sampling the 50 Hz sine wave at 20 points*

Depending whereabouts the first sample lies and the 20th sample lies on the sampled waveform, can produce errors of this magnitude. A much higher sampling rate would reduce this error to nearly zero. Or, if you can arrange to use a PLL (phase-locked-loop) generating sample points that are locked to the incoming AC waveform frequency (but 20x higher), that would solve this problem.

> *I am sampling the 50 Hz sine wave at 20 points using a timer and then
> averaging the same*

To measure RMS you need to square each sample, then average the new squared samples then take the square root.

Comment: I will try with a higher sampling rate and see the functionality, IIRC I had tried doubling the rate and averaging over half a cycle, but the problem was worse. i am not doing RMS because its a 8bit uC so I wanted to avoid "heavy" calculations.

Comment: @MumbaiVerve I've used 8-bit ALUs running at relatively slow speed and would not find RMS computations at 1 kHz measurement rate a problem. It's just a little bit of assembly code. Runs very fast. DO NOT USE FP!!!!